# startActivityOnResult() in recycler view onitemClick()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener, startactivityforresult

so I need to create a notes app, in which user opens and sees a RecyclerView-grid of notes. on clicking any note, it opens a new activity `SecondActivity` with 2 edit texts `title` and `data`.
 On closing `secondActivity`, I want the user to see the title he had set in `secondActivity` on the grid he clicked on the main page.HOW?

After searching for a white, i got this **`startActivityForResult().`** i understood its working, but it is not available in the adapter/holder, where my onitemclicklistener is present.

So how can i get to recieve this title? can I use the saveInstanceState bundle for this work?I also researched and observed that a child Acticvity's(`SecondActivity`) onSaveInstanceState is not called when  the `secondActivity` is destroyed. so maybe that bundle thing would be a wrong path.In my `OnBindHolder()` function, i was  using `myholder.itemview.getContext().startActivity(...,...)` for calling the secondActivity. I also tried passing the context for main Activity in adapter and using it for starting activity, but it still didn't show `startActivityForResult()` ...

**UPDATE:**
here are the java classes from my app(I have explained in detail about my problem in a comment in Main Activity.java):

- [MainActivity.java](https://pastebin.com/sPnmCwDS)
- [Details.java](https://pastebin.com/qYcWd8fU)
  (Reycler View Files:)
- [RVadapter.java](https://pastebin.com/HsvFkKhk)
- [RVholder.java](https://pastebin.com/YapYamYk)
- [RVdata.java](https://pastebin.com/gL7HjcCf)
- [RVfeeder.java](https://pastebin.com/Pn4vhmhf)

[githubLink](https://github.com/chaostools/9notes)

Comment: could you provide the whole code !!!! The question needs to be more formatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast `Context` to `Activity` because it has `startActivityForResult`.

```
((Activity) context).startActivityForResult()
```

or

```
(((Activity) itemView.getContext()).startActivityForResult()
```